# CodeIgniter does not work on the server while it does on my localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have created a profile page for my organization staff. Each staff profile information can be seen when his/her email typed. For example:

```
http://localhost/people/zkanoca
```

will show my information. By the way it works on my local computer.

I have decided to take a test my application. Then I have uploaded all the files and changed the database access information.

To see how it works I typed:

```
http://people.example.com/zkanoca
```

I got 404 error. So I notified that it is a mod_rewrite issue. Then I re-typed the url as:

```
http://people.example.com/index.php/zkanoca
```

Now I am getting error:

> Unable to locate the model you have specified: Header_model

`Header_model` is a class in `header_model.php` in models directory.

I have double checked the class names, file names, routes. There is no letter case problem. It works on local but not on the server. I have searched for a solution to my problem on Internet but none of them helped me. Also I am working with CodeIgniter 3.0rc3.

I am sure I forget to set something for remote server but could have not identified yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try .htaccess with the rewrite rule

`Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: I do not think it is a .htaccess issue. I have also tried your suggestion. No help (:

Comment: I use my own organization's web server.

Comment: Is the website hosted on a linux server ? If so change the filename(s) to match the class names as linux files are case sensitive. `class MY_Class => MY_Class.php`

Comment: @Philip, I am also using Linux server, but the files are not case sensitive there. Do you have any idea why they are different for different servers?

Comment: @prasanthprem You would have to ask your host about that mate.